# can not update ubuntu, failed to download files

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and get :

```
ravit@ubuntu:/$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:1 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [72 B]                       
Get:2 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release [11.9 kB]                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:3 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources [14 B]                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]           
Get:5 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages [14 B]                
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [63.5 kB]             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [87.4 kB]        
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [2,061 B]  
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [28.1 kB]    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [2,337 B] 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [72 B]                  
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]         
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [290 kB]  
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg [933 B]       
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release [11.9 kB]                   
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]           
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release [63.5 kB]         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources [14 B]                 
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [212 kB]       
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [8,846 B]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [111 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3,854 B]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [3,433 B]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [159 kB] 
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [123 kB]   
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [5,151 B]
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en [1,679 B]
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en [2,266 B]
Get:29 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [64.0 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [548 kB] 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [11.8 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [292 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [12.1 kB]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [271 kB]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [6,148 B]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,774 B]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [154 kB]
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources [5,851 B]    
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources [28 B] 
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources [28.4 kB]
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources [1,898 B]
Get:42 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages [6,285 B]
Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages [28 B]
Get:44 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages [32.6 kB]
Get:45 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [1,552 B]
Get:46 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en [3,645 B]
Get:47 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en [1,215 B]
Get:48 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en [14 B]
Get:49 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en [29.6 kB]
Fetched 2,731 kB in 11s (242 kB/s)                                             
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What's the problem ? ( i'm using Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04 )

Answer (score 1):

A simple frequently reoccurring question asked in the wrong place to provide a verbose answer has a simple solution, in this case two of them since you received two different types of common package management error messages.

1. Remove the PPAs that no longer exist from your software sources. From the Dash select *Software & Updates*, then *Other Software* tab ->  remove all of the PPA software sources that no longer exist by unticking them. The software sources that you need to remove are the ones that caused you the get the `404 Not Found` error messages when running `sudo apt-get update`.
2. You also have one malformed line in your software sources. Remove this line manually from `/etc/apt/sources.list` by following the instructions in [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list).

Answer (score 0):

Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135932/apt-get-update-failure-to-fetch-cant-connect-to-any-sources):

Evidently apt can't handle very many software sources, so I was able to solve my problem by deselecting all except the one I needed to access. This would be a real pain to do frequently, but it's better than nothing. From the site:

> From the "Other Software" tab, disable all PPA repositories, leaving
>   only the official Ubuntu repositories active. Enabling too many PPA
>   repositories (which are non-official) can cause your package manager
>   to become unstable.